# Access violation for a specific function

Tags: c++

I have many functions in my CustomerList.cpp file, the only one of which that doesn't work is shown below (and the break point is marked with a comment). NOTE: Store class is correct, and m_pHead is a CustomerList private variable (but that shouldn't matter).

```
bool CustomerList::removeStore(int ID)
{

    Store *back, *temp;

    if(m_pHead = NULL)
        {
            cout << "\nError! Store " << ID << " not found in the List!\n";
            system("pause");
            return false; // nothing to delete
        }

    // Search for the item to delete
    back = NULL;
    temp = m_pHead;

    while((temp != NULL) && (temp->getStoreID() != ID))
    {
        back = temp;
        temp = temp->m_pNext;
    }

    if(back == NULL)    // Delete the first item in the list
    {
        m_pHead = temp->m_pNext; // THE FUNCTION BREAKS HERE
        delete temp;
        cout << "\nSuccess! Store " << ID << " added to List!\n";
        system("pause");
        return true;
    }
    else if(temp != NULL)  // Delete from middle or end of list
    {
        back->m_pNext = temp->m_pNext;
        delete temp;
        cout << "\nSuccess! Store " << ID << " added to List!\n";
        system("pause");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nError! Store " << ID << " not found in the List!\n";
        system("pause");
        return false;    // Didn't find the item to delete
    }

}
```

Every time I make a call to this function, it breaks, even if the ID of the Store is not on the list (it shouldn't make it that far in the function).
Here is an example of a call:

```
// Creating a new Customer List
CustomerList *newList = new CustomerList();
newList->removeStore(3);
```

What in the world am I doing wrong?

Comment: The short answer is that `temp` is probably NULL.  It looks doubly suspicious since the loop just above seems to advance until it is NULL or you get a match.  Use the debugger to examine the state when it crashes and trace line by line to see if it is doing what you thought t would.

Comment: Well, the likely reason is that `temp == NULL`.  Especially if the list is empty.   

Are you certain that the last element in the list always has m_pNext == NULL?

Are you certain that it's crashing at the line you specify?  If you're using a debugger, what is `temp`?

Comment: `if(m_pHead = NULL)` is assigning NULL to `m_pHead`, not comparing `m_pHead` to see if it is NULL.

Comment: @RemyLebeau nails it.

Comment: Which basically means that the list is empty 'cause you've thrown it all away.

Comment: this is why I use `if ( !m_pHead )` and Yoda condition... although I'm sure others will say that you should just use a compiler that warns about possibly incorrect assignment :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau You sir, just saved me 1.5 hours of scratching my head and looking like an idiot... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some logic errors in your code.  Most notably, this line;

```
if(m_pHead = NULL)
```

Is **assigning `NULL` to `m_pHead`** before then comparing it.  Thus, `temp` is NULL, and `back` remains NULL, which is why your code reaches the spot you commented and crashes.

You need to use the `==` comparison operator, not the `=` assignment operator (your compiler should have warned you about that):

```
if(m_pHead == NULL)
```

Or safer:

```
if(!m_pHead)
```

Now, with that said, you can simplify the rest of the code to the following:

```
bool CustomerList::removeStore(int ID)
{
    Store *temp, *previous;

    // Search for the item to delete

    previous = NULL;
    temp = m_pHead;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->getStoreID() == ID)
        {
            if (m_pHead == temp)
            {
                // Deleting the first item in the list
                m_pHead = temp->m_pNext;
            }

            if (previous != NULL)
            {
                // Deleting from middle or end of list
                previous->m_pNext = temp->m_pNext;
            }

            delete temp;
            cout << "\nSuccess! Store " << ID << " removed from List!\n";
            system("pause");
            return true;
        }

        previous = temp;
        temp = temp->m_pNext;
    }

    cout << "\nError! Store " << ID << " not found in the List!\n";
    system("pause");
    return false; // nothing to delete
}
```

Or, if you use a standard C++ container, such as `std::list`, instead of making your own manual linked-list, you can do this instead:

```
struct isStoreID
{
    int m_id;
    isStoreID(int id) : m_id(id) {}
    bool operator()(const Store &store) { return (store.getStoreID() == m_id); }
};

bool CustomerList::removeStore(int ID)
{
    // Search for the item to delete

    // where m_list is a std::list<Store>...
    std::list<Store>::iterator iter = std::find_if(m_list.begin(), m_list.end(), isStoreID(ID));

    bool bWasFound = (iter != m_list.end());
    if (bWasFound)
    {
        m_list.erase(iter);
        cout << "\nSuccess! Store " << ID << " removed from List!\n";
    }
    else
        cout << "\nError! Store " << ID << " not found in the List!\n";

    system("pause");
    return bWasFound;
}
```